# is it possible to get memory block size allocated by 'new'?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, memory-management, c++builder

Hello i need to record my heap, but now i am just thinking to overload 'new' operator with my function.

I need to summary the real count bytes of memory that was increased after malloc() or Heap*() or other windows mem* functions

But for now i need to analyze current heap implementation. Is it possible to get blocks size like allocated by HeapAlloc() function - HeapSize() ?

.

Comment: You know how large the block is, because you asked for a certain size in the first place.

Comment: Yes, that is i am now developing this

Comment: ... although the allocator could return a larger block than what you asked for, and I don't know if there is any way to detect that.

Comment: And what if you didn't allocate the memory, what if some other third parties lib did and you wanted to test some condition based on that fact so that you don't overflow the memory... THAT would be a pain, but these situations occurs...

Answer (score 0):

I can see that you did not search the documentation.

[`HeapSize()` exists.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366706%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)

---

**Edit** On reflection, perhaps you were asking for an *alternative* to `HeapSize()` that you can use when you performed allocation yourself with `new`.

The answer is no. The standard allocation routines don't have anything to grab information about the memory block, because:

- That's highly implementation-dependent, and
- You already know the block size (because you specified it in the first place), so what would be the point of the bloat?

In fact `HeapSize()` *is* the implementation-dependent function for Windows that does this, but you can only use it when you performed a `HeapAlloc()`.

There's [also non-standard] `_msize` that can be used with `malloc` and friends, but `new` *may not use `malloc`*.

Therefore I suggest that you just track the sizes yourself in your allocator.

Comment: new can really allocate by using other mehanisms insted of HeapAlloc()

Answer (score 0):

[_msize](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/msize)

According to the documentation it works for **calloc,malloc and realloc**.

However, at least under Visual Studio, using the default allocator, it works also for **new**.

It is not a good idea to use it, however, it may do the work for your analysis.

One more thing:

External tools such as [VMMap](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/dd535533) may help for such analysis.

Comment: `new` might not always use `malloc`.